# Which assembly has to be referenced to work with Windows.Web.Syndication?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Which assembly has to be referenced to work with Windows.Web.Syndication and SyndicationClient in particular?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.syndication.syndicationclient.aspx

I have checked my Reference Manager of my WPF application but I couldn't find such assembly.

Comment: "my WPF application" - at first glance it looks like it's a Windows Metro / Windows Store API.

Comment: true but still it should exist in an assembly somewhere?!

Comment: Did you ever figure out where it is?

Answer (score 1):

Add nuget package: Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts)

[Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)

Or use Nuget: System.ServiceModel.Syndication

[Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Syndication/)

[RSS Parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/parsers/rssparser)